# Not able to find the correct Odoo models

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, xmlrpclib, odoo-website

So, I need to add customer, order, order_items(products), products(list of them that company is selling) data using external API to Odoo.

I am so far done with customers but I am pretty confused about the models that are needed for the rest. sale.order looks like it is for orders but rest I am not able to find.
I have checked sales.order.line, but as each customer can have multiple orders and each order can have multiple products. In this case, that is not so matching. (Many2one relationship is mostly there)

Could anyone please help me to find the most suiting models? As I am really new to Odoo, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Technical -> database structure -> Models` (after activating the developer mode in Developer Tools which you can locate at the bottom of General Settings view). Select your model, then in the field's list views locate a `Many2one` field and click on it to display a form view with different fields and the `Object Relation` is what you are looking for.

You can also see the required field needed to create a record.